# Tuleap 8.7 on Centos 6.6 "My Account" page blank

Tags: centos, tuleap

I have just installed Tuleap V8.7 on Centos 6.6 using the instructions at

http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html

The installation seems to have run without error and I can log in as the admin user using the generated password provided by install.sh

However when I try to open the "My Account" page so I can change the password I just get a blank page.

This also happens if I try to go to "My Account" for any users I create too.

The problem is the same whether I use Firefox or Chrome as the browser.

Please can anyone advise what the problem might be or how I can fix it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case it's cause was IM plugin. So at least you should try to disable the IM plugin.